# Storing information from ArrayList in an external file for later use

Tags: java, file, arraylist, io

My assignment this week was the create a virtual ATM that could perform basic functions like add, withdrawal, and check balance.

The problem I'm running into is storing user information in a file for later use.

If a user has an account already, I need to have all of their account information stored somewhere so I can pull it up if they have a matching ID and PIN number.

If a user does not have an account, then I need to have them fill out a form, have it generate an account number, a PIN, along with a initial deposit. I have all of this done except for actually storing it into a file for later use.

I was thinking to have each new user object stored into an `ArrayList`, and then have it written to an external file.

However I have never had to do this before, and I've been searching around and I can't seem to find something that works for me.

So my main question is, how can I store the `ArrayList` of users into an external file, and how can I go back later and pull them back into the program when the user has a matching ID and PIN, that way they can add or remove money from their account.

Here is the code I have already

**ATM / Main Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATM {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //variables
    String dash = "-------------------\n";

    // Scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Welcome screen
    System.out.print(dash);
    System.out.print("Welcome to the Bank\n");
    System.out.print(dash);

    System.out.println("Do you have an account with us? (y/n) ");

    String answer = scanner.nextLine();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

    } else {

        // new user is created
        Bank bank = new Bank();

        System.out.println("Enter your full name below (e.g. John M. Smith): ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Create a username: ");
        String userName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your starting deposit amount: ");
        int balance = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print(dash);
        System.out.print("Generating your information...\n");
        System.out.print(dash);

        int pin = bank.PIN();
        String accountNum = bank.accountNum();

        User user = new User(name, userName, pin, accountNum, balance);

        //new user gets added to the array list
        Bank.users.add(user);

        System.out.println(user);
    }


}
```

}

**Bank Class with PIN, Account Number generator, and `ArrayList`**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random; 
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Bank {

//Generate a random 16 digit bank account number
public String accountNum() {

    int max = 9999;
    int min = 1000;

    int a1 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    int a2 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    int a3 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    int a4 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    String accountNum = a1 + "-" + a2 + "-" + a3 + "-" + a4;

    return accountNum;
}

//Generate a random 4 digit PIN
public int PIN() {

    int max = 9999;
    int min = 1000;

    int PIN = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    return PIN;
}

//array list for users
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>() {

};
```

}

**User class, User object is here**

```
public class User {

String name;
String userName;
String accountNum;
int pin;
int balance;

public User(String name, String userName, int pin, String accountNum, int balance) {

    this.name = name;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.accountNum = accountNum;
    this.pin = pin;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public String toString() {

    return "Name: " + this.name + "\n\nUsername: " + this.userName + " | " + "Pin: " + this.pin + "\n\n"
             + "Account Number: " + this.accountNum + "\n\nAccount Balance: $" + this.balance + 
            "\n\nNever share your login information with anyone!";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your objects into XML files. To do it, refer to API such as JAXB to make Java/XML conversions.

FYI, if i had the same issue to work on, i would use a database rather than files : easier to maintain, update and make some searches on objects attributes or values.
For instance, PostgreSQL is free and easy to use.

Comment: Is it something that could be easily integrated? I have to hand this in when I'm done and I don't want my teacher to have to do anything else besides opening the program.

Comment: When you will install your database management tool, a dedicated service will run automatically to handle DB calls.
To store your objects in DB, you can use frameworks such as Hibernate. If you are a beginner, start your developement by using simple JDBC calls. An update of your code can be made later to implement a framework of your choice.
So yes, the all of that can be easily integrated.